# What does the parameter "i" represent in the callable functions in Ride4dApps?

Tags: blockchain, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

I'm totally new to Ride4dApps and while trying to write a callable function I did not understand what the parameter `i` stands for here `@Callable(i)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `@callable(i)` to be able to access the data for an invoked function.

The parameter `i` is of type Invocation and basically Invocation is a data structure of:

```
caller: Address.
payment: Payment|Un, where Payment consist of amount: Long and assetId: ByteVector | Unit.
```